# Conditionally displaying using ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to conditionally display using ng-show in angular and it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong ?

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">   
    <select ng-model="type" ng-init="type='WEP'">
      <option value="None">None</option>
      <option value="WEP">WEP</option>
      <option value="WPA">WPA</option>
      <option value="WEP Admin">WEP Admin</option>
    </select>
    <p ng-show="type == 'WEP' || 'WPA' ">{{type}}</p>
</body>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/jvqW2w6hg6gq6YVsjAgh?p=preview

Comment: try `type == 'WEP' || type == 'WPA'`

Answer (score 1):

```
<p ng-show="type == 'WEP' || type == 'WPA' ">{{type}}</p>
```

please try this.

Comment: May I ask what makes you use "==" instead of "===", I don't see any good reason to do type conversion in this case. Since "===" is proven to be faster than "==". http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-comparisons

Comment: Null and Undefined types are compared using "==" (but not ===). [i.e. Null==Undefined (but not Null===Undefined)]. for further reference please have a look into this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: and there are many other comparison that required to be done with === and not with ==.

Comment: I know the difference between "==" and "===". I'm just saying in this case there is no reason to use "==" since you got a string literal. You should use "===".

Comment: No in this case it is not required